# display record to longdate unixtime into date using mysql like 2018-03-17 to 2018-03-20

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

But this query is displayed wrong data.
I want to display from to date data.I have converted unixtime to date now i want to display record using calender.

```
 SELECT * FROM `tbl_user` 
 WHERE DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(registeredOn)) between '2018-03-17' AND '2018-03-17'
```

Answer (score 2):

The `FROM_UNIXTIME` function already returns a datetime, so your call to `DATE` is unnecessary.  If you want to target the full day `2018-03-17`, then use this where clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_user
WHERE
    FROM_UNIXTIME(registeredOn) >= '2018-03-17' AND    -- March 17 at midnight
    FROM_UNIXTIME(registeredOn) < '2018-03-18';        -- March 18 at midnight
```

That being said, your current query actually should be returning records assuming any registration dates exist on `2018-03-17`.  If not, then the problem is your data, not your query.

Comment: if I want to take date from 2018-03-17 to 2018-03-17 then data will not display. what should I do?

Comment: @MangalOneVoice But it should display, if there is data from that date.  Even your original query should have worked.  Edit your question with actual data and we can take a closer look.